# I wish you best (wishes, greetings, regards) What word would be the best for a birthday?

Tags: word-usage

I wish you best (wishes, greetings, regards) What word would be the best for a birthday?

I remember that wish means that i want something but i don't have(desire). Could wish be used in the above context? thanks.

Comment: You _send_ best wishes (hopes that the day will be a good one for them).

Answer (score 1):

"Best Wishes" is most common for birthdays.

"Greetings" tends to be used for holidays.

"Best regards" is a way of signing off any letter informally, and is not particularly associated with any occasion.

Comment: Thanks, i understand now

Comment: _Birthday greetings_ seems normal enough to me.